# 320amp meter- 2 200amp disconnects- 2 main panels

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a 320amp service with 2- 200amp disconnects and 2 main panels- I one on house with ground rod and the disconnect is bonded to ground. The second disconnect is bonded to ground but feeds a shop 100feet away, with only 3 wires, should there be a second ground rod at the shop? And this panel bonded to ground?
If I am required to pull a ground wire from disconnect to remote panel can I dig the trench and lay it along side the existing conduit? (The conduit is PVC)

Comment: What is the age (date of construction/installation of power service), and are the wires in **metallic** conduit?

Comment: PVC pipe-date unknown

Answer (score 1):

There should be a ground connection at the shop building. Preferably an Ufer (concrete encased electrode) in the foundation, but more typically a ground rod or two since Ufers require planning for a Ufer when the concrete is poured.

If the wires run in **metallic** conduit, or overhead on a steel cable, there's a suitable conductor for ground from the disconnect already present.

If the installation is old, 3-wire connections were disallowed once an area adopted NEC 2008. But a pre-existing one is grandfathered as built. For a 3-wire built before NEC 2008, the sub-panel is bonded. For a 4-wire built after, or retrofitted to meet later code due to renovations or owner safety concerns, the sub-panel is unbonded (neutral and ground are isolated in the sub-panel.)

Since you have PVC conduit in place, you should be able to pull a grounding wire through that, rather than digging alongside it. It may be easiest to pull out the wires that are in it, add the grounding wire, and pull all 4 back in, but you might be able to just pull in the grounding wire without removing the others. Either would be less work than digging 100 feet of trench.